# Solving $\int \frac{x \arctan x}{1+x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to compute integral $$\int \frac{x \arctan x}{1+x^2} dx$$

**My approach:** I tried to solve this by substituting $x = \tan t$ which ended up to the integral of $\int x \tan x$. I am not able to figure out how to compute $\int x \tan x$.

Edit: Answer given is $x - \frac{\arctan x}{\sqrt1+x^2}$. However I am not sure about the correctness of the answer.

Thanks for help

Comment: You mean $\arctan$ by $\tan^{-1}$ or $1/\tan$?

Comment: I mean arc tan. Thanks

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+xtan%28x%29&t=crmtb01) doesn't give an elementary primitive.

Comment: There is an answer to $\int x \tan x$ involving [Clausen's Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClausensIntegral.html) given in this [Quora question](https://www.quora.com/How-do-we-integrate-int-x-tan-x-dx)

Comment: The given answer seems incorrect to me. Are you sure you posted the correct integral? Because it does not have an elementary anti-derivative. The result will contain [dilogarithmic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function) terms.

Comment: Please review your stated problem, to make sure you have no typos.

Comment: The given integrand has no analytic antiderivative and the given answer does not lead to a simple derivative. Both seem wrong !

Comment: @amWhy Dear sir answer may be wrong. As answer is not from a very trusted source.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback/comment, dear srijan.  But please note addressing me as "sir" is inappropriate.  I understand you meant only to be respectful; but please be aware that not everyone contributing to math.se is male.

Comment: @amWhy Thank you so much. I agreed with your opinion  and advice. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Express $\arctan$ in its [logarithmic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Logarithmic_forms).

$$\int\dfrac{x\arctan(x)}{1 + x^2}\,\mathrm dx = \int\dfrac{\mathrm ix\left(\ln(1 - \mathrm ix) - \ln(1 + \mathrm ix)\right)}{2\left(1 + x^2\right)}\,\mathrm dx$$

Comment: Why the down vote? The answer is valid.